# Setting the cell on NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell

I have a custom `NSTextFieldCell` that i want to set on a `NSTextField`.
If i set it on the IB it works fine.

[image]

And this gets it working like this:

[image]

But i want to set it programmatically and i try something like this:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{

    NSRect theRect = NSRectFromCGRect( NSMakeRect(50, 100, 100, 100));
    NSTextField *inputField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:theRect];
    DRKHUDTextFieldCell *theC = [[DRKHUDTextFieldCell alloc] initTextCell:@"textfield"];
    [inputField setCell:theC];

    [[_window contentView] addSubview:inputField];

    }
```

This is the result i get:

[image]

What is going wrong? Is my code bad or what?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working solution in swift. Above Objective C answer was not complete and hence didn't work for me.

```
let cell = CustomTextFieldCell(textCell: "")
self.cell = cell
self.isBordered = true
self.backgroundColor = .white
self.isBezeled = true
self.bezelStyle = .squareBezel
self.isEnabled = true
self.isEditable = true
self.isSelectable = true
```

You need to reset all the properties if you replace `cell` property. These are default values, try setting your own values matching your case.

Comment: hey mate, it has been 3 three years, i don't even remember what i was trying to do. Thanks for your time though, it might help someone else.

Comment: @ozmax, Thanks. Please accept answer so people know there is a working solution

Comment: @adev It's not a solution, bc now you have to subclass two objects (textfield and its cell)

Comment: @JohnSmith, I am not sure if we need to subclass textfield since this has been a while and I don't remember if I was sub-classing that time. I had the same issue as in question and this is what fixed for me. Hence shared it for others benefit. I am hoping this same answer would work for cases where you are using directly `NSTextField` and somewhere you can set properties like this.(Note: Question was already about setting a subclassed cell, so that part is fine I guess)

Comment: @adev Look, the problem is that even by subclassing nstextfield, you can't set any custom cell, not even a default NSCell(). If you set it at least programmatically, nothing will appear. I've spend a log time on it and the only option is to create a NSTextField in a storyboard or nib file and set the custom cell there

Comment: @JohnSmith, That is not true at least till an year back. I was subclassing and setting custom cell in my project at that time and that worked fine. Unfortunately I don't work with that company anymore so I dont have that code. But this was working fine for me without setting it in storyboard/xib. Probably you are doing something wrong in your code. It is worth asking a separate question since current question is not related to that. Take a look at this class [here](https://github.com/akhilcb/ACBTokenField/blob/master/Sources/ACBTokenField/Extensions/NSTokenField%2BACBExtension.swift) for eg:

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, It is working fine:

```
 NSRect theRect = NSRectFromCGRect( NSMakeRect(50, 100, 100, 100));

    NSTextField *inputField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:theRect];

    NSTextFieldCell *theC = [[NSTextFieldCell alloc] initTextCell:@"textfield"];

    [inputField setCell:theC];

    [inputField setBordered:YES];

    [inputField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];

    [inputField setBezeled:YES];

    [inputField setBezelStyle:0];

   [[_window contentView] addSubview:inputField];
```